# Calculating side of Pythagorus theorem, using functions

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the side of a Pythagorus theorem. I wrote my code, but I can't seem to get it to actually calculate and I'm not sure where I'm doing it wrongly.

```
from math import sqrt

def calc_side_c (a,b):
    a = 6
    b = 10
    calc_side_c = round(sqrt(pow(a) + pow(b)), 2)
    return calc_side_c 

print("c = " , calc_side_c)
```

Comment: You are calling your function incorrectly.  It looks like you had some regular inline statements and put a `def` at the top and a `return` at the bottom.  This is not how functions work.

Comment: You could do this in a one-liner, without any imports: `return (a ** 2 + b ** 2) ** 0.5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `pow` function requires a second parameter with the exponent you're raising it to (in this case, 2). Line 6 should read:

```
    calc_side_c = round(sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)), 2)
```

2. You didn't call the function with any parameters. In order to call a function, you need to write the function name followed by parentheses enclosing your parameters (in this case, your values for `a` and `b`). The last line should read:

```
    print("c = " , calc_side_c(6, 10))
```

You can replace 6 and 10 with whatever value you please.

3. You shouldn't be overwriting the values of `a` and `b` inside the function. Remove the lines that read:

```
    a = 6
    b = 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn’t call the function, you should’ve done
`print("c = ", calc_side_c(A, B))`
Instead of
`print("c = ", calc_side_c)`
Also inside the function `calc_side_c` you override the variables a,b that you get as a function parameters. (You overrode them with 6 and 10).
In addition `pow` requires a second parameter for the exponent.